# Aforge.Net FFMPEG alternative

Tags: windows, open-source, library, c#, .net

I use [Aforege.Video.FFMPEG](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/) library in a C# project to create a video from a series of bitmaps. Recently for a weird reason the project doesn't work and gives an error on this library when I call `WriteVideoFrame` method.

Anyway, I decided to find an alternative for this library to be:

- Free and Open source
- For C# .Net in Windows (.Net framework 4.5 or lower)

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details.